# How can I modify the bootloader config on debian 7

Tags: debian, grub

I want to install Debian 7 remotely. I've followed this tutorial:
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Remote

How can I execute Step 8?

I found the command `update-grub` but I don't know where to write the config.

Answer (score 1):

The location of bootloader configuration files will depend both on the (presumably non-Debian) Linux distribution of the target machine and on the actual bootloader being used. On x86(-64) machines, Grub and LILO are the most popular bootloaders, but on armel/armhf and embedded devices the bootloader might be u-boot, coreboot, redpill or something else.

For Grub, `/boot` might contain the source configuration files directly, or that partition may only contain compiled configuration generated from source configuration in `/etc/` or `/etc/grub.d/`.

For embedded bootloaders, the configuration file might be plain text in `/boot/`, could be a compiled binary configuration file in a separate EEPROM or flash chip, or could even be hardcoded directly into the bootloader executable and stored in the first raw sectors of the system disk (not as part of a partition).